# extracting source code line before and after logging statement

Tags: python, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to extract the source code line before and after the logging statement using astor and python AST, thanks to the answers available on my previous StackOverflow question:

```
import ast
import astor
import json
class LogPrinter(astor.TreeWalk):
    def pre_Call(self):
        if (isinstance(self.cur_node.func, ast.Attribute) and
            isinstance(self.cur_node.func.value, ast.Name) and
            (self.cur_node.func.value.id.lower() == "logging" or self.cur_node.func.value.id.lower() == "log" or self.cur_node.func.value.id.lower() == "logger")
           ):
            print(astor.to_source(self.cur_node))
       
    def post_Call(self):
        if (isinstance(self.cur_node.func, ast.Attribute)):
            print(astor.to_source(self.cur_node))
```

I can get logging statements from the above code but I am not able to get complete preceding and following statements:

example:

```
def db_contecton(string url):
    if URL:
        #multiline logger
        logger.debug(
        "connecting to 
        URL : " +url)
        #multiline source code
        db = db
        .conn.
        init()
        db.connect(url)
        #multiline logger
        logger.
        info("connection 
        to DB 
        successful")
```

The output that I am trying to get is:
1)

```
if url:
logger.debug("connecting to URL : " +url)
db = db.conn.init()
```

and
2)

```
db = db.conn.init()
db.connect(url)
logger.info("connection to DB successful")
```

NOTE: multiline loggers and source code is converted into single line

At this point I can extract loggers and get the following statement which does not have the complete source code:
my current output is

```
#the statement above logger is missing
logger.debug("connecting to URL : " +url) 
db.conn.init() #the db variable is missing should be db = db.conn.init()
```

The above are just example snippets of python source code that may not be logically correct.

Comment: I have updated the question, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understood your question: Do you want to parse python files as text and extract the 1 above and 1 below lines wherever it has some *logging related* code?

You could read the file as text, break it into lines, match with your desired words (e.g.: *logger, logging, log*), keep the indexes of those lines and then do whatever you want with it:

```
log_words = 'logger logging log'.split()

python_files = ['file1.py', 'file2.py']

keep = dict()

for f in python_files:
    keep[f] = []
    with open(f, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                for w in log_words:
                    if w in lines[i]:
                      keep[f].append(i - 1) # previous line
                      keep[f].append(i)     # actual line
                      keep[f].append(i + 1) # next line
```

It checks each line for each desired word for each given file.
It's not performatic though.
But i believe it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not work for me, what if loggers are multiline and the previous line and line below it are also multiline? let me edit the question to remove the confusion

Comment: First things first: did i understand your needs correctly?

Comment: no, how can one extract multiline loggers and multiline source code commands with the approach that you shared, I think one needs AST to parse and get the required information.